# What does "rake test:functionals" do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am brand new to ruby, and am starting to build a little shopping cart app, as a basic introduction.  I was editing a test file, in the directory /test/functional/ but made a typo and hit enter, after typing "rake test:functionals" into the CLI.

I don't know enough about what this does, or how I can go back to where I was before.  When I first tried it, everything was fine, but then when I tried to add some additional functionality it fell apart.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"rake test:functionals" is to run all your rails functional tests which are testing the rails controllers functionality.

You can look at [rails guide on testing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#functional-tests-for-your-controllers) for further information, the link also explain other kind of test in rails.